# cloudwatch missing metrics

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm probably missing something extremely obvious but I only see 6 metrics on my cloudwatch -- 4 EC2 (all about CPU Credits) and 2 for S3 (bucket size and # of objects).  It feels like there should be ... you know more than 6 metrics?  I really only have one EC2 instance on this account and it is currently stopped, but it runs every day for about half an hour.  I should be able to see its metrics, right?

[image]

Comment: Sure, hit the blue "Browse Metrics" button on the Cloudwatch console's main page. Should be right under a line of text saying something like "You currently have 1,710 CloudWatch metrics available in the US West (Oregon) region."

Comment: well, that's the thing -- it only shows 6 for me!

Comment: Are you in the right region?

Comment: in what sense am I in the right region?  My instance is in us-east-1b.

Comment: OK, so you're in the right spot. Is this a brand-new account and/or instance? Or has stuff in this account been running for at least a few days already?

Comment: This has been setup over a year ago.

Comment: I'm out of ideas, then, and would suggest reaching out to AWS Support.

Answer (score 0):

Was your stopped instance stopped over 3 hours ago?  The CloudWatch console defaults to a 3 hour view.  Change the time period by looking in the upper right for the text "1g 3h 12h 1d 3d 1w custom", and choose 1w.  Expect to see at least the 9 metrics per instance that are documented at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/ec2-metricscollected.html#ec2-metrics

Comment: the number of metrics doesn't change no matter what time period i chose.